# Implied cross currency curve

Tags: interest-rates, fx, derivatives, trading

For EM countries without a liquid xccy curve, how I can imply it from local government bonds or swaps?

Comment: There's always some liquid Xccy curve, even for EM: I have never come across an example of a currency  with a non-existent xccy curve. Anyway, for tenors up to two years, if the xccy curve doesn't trade outright, it can be implied from FX swaps; see the formula in this post here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/aud-funding-rates/61483?r=SearchResults#61483

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question on Xccy swaps curve observability](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59157/question-on-xccy-swaps-curve-observability)

Comment: Also related https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55203